# How can I use Syncfusion Vue Examples with Stack blitz

Tags: syncfusion, stackblitz

I want to use stackblitz with syncfusion - specifically a grid inline editing example. I can almost get it going , but I can't get the Material design styles to display. I am a newbie to syncfusion and stack blitz

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply material style design by referring the material.css file in the sample as below.

```
<style>

@import "https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css";

</style>
```

[Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-u01rq)